# How can I get all records from one table, even if there are no corresponding records in the JOINed table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of `[Users]`, simplified for this example:

```
uID | uName | uSalesRep
----+-------+----------
  1 | John  | 1
  2 | Bob   | 1
  3 | Fred  | 1
  4 | Stu   | 1
```

And a table of sales `[Activity]`:

```
aID | aDate      | aUserID | aText
----+------------+---------+---------------
  1 | 2013-10-09 |       1 | John did stuff
  2 | 2013-10-14 |       2 | Bob did stuff
  3 | 2013-10-17 |       3 | Fred did stuff
```

I want to get a list of **all sales reps**, together with their activity for the week beginning 14th October 2013, and here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
SELECT uID, Name, aID, aDate, aText
FROM [Users]
LEFT JOIN [Activity] ON uID = UserID
WHERE (aDate >= '2013-10-14' OR aDate = NULL)
AND (aDate <= '2013-10-18' OR aDate = NULL)
AND uSalesRep = 1
```

I used a `LEFT JOIN` in the hope of retrieving all reps, but I think this is being overridden by the `aDate` requirements. Including `aDate = NULL` includes reps with no activity at all, but reps who have activity outside the specified range are being omitted.

How can I get all the reps at least once, regardless of any activity they have recorded?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the filter applies to the joined table, you need to put the filter on the `join`, not in the `where` clause

```
SELECT uID, Name, aID, aDate, aText
FROM [Users]
LEFT JOIN [Activity] ON uID = UserID
AND (aDate >= '2013-10-14')
AND (aDate <= '2013-10-18')
WHERE uSalesRep = 1
```

Comment: I had no idea that further conditions could be applied to `JOIN`s. Thank you.